# How to do redirect in JavaScript Single-Page Application to ensure Google passes link equity from old page?

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, single-page-application, google-crawlers

Let's say, I want /foo page to be redirected with 301 status to /bar page, and all link juice transferred from /foo to /bar.

How can I do that in a single-page app if a backend always returns index.html with 200 code and JavaScript handles all routing?

Basically I'm looking to replicate the effect of a regular 301 redirect within in a single-page app.

Comment: You can not do an HTTP redirect via JavaScript – the server has to answer the request with that status code directly. // If you just want Google to index /bar instead of /foo, then set the canonical URL for /foo to /bar.

Comment: Yes, we need it just for google. If I point old page with canonical tag to the new page, it I'll require me to keep both of these pages alive. It's not a redirect.

Comment: Again, you can not do an HTTP redirect via client-side JavaScript. If you want the response to an HTTP request to be a 301 status code and a `Location` header, then your _server_ has to respond with that. Your server is the one that _receives_ the HTTP request made by the client (the Google bot in this case), so only your server can _answer_ it with an HTTP redirect.

Comment: I understand, that's why I'm asking how to do similar in the fronted, and make google crawler understand that.

Comment: If you don’t want to keep `/foo` available, then you don’t have any “frontend” when a client requests that URL.

Comment: Frontend handles all routing with html5 pushState. Which means whatever address you try to access, it will load index.html. And then JS decides what should be rendered.

Comment: _“Which means whatever address you try to access, it will load index.html”_ – which means, Google bot will get a status code 200 OK for all resources requested, no matter if they “exist” or not. And that is all it cares about – 200 OK means it got a “valid” answer.

Comment: Exactly! It's my question.

Comment: And my answer is, still: Can’t be done that way.

Comment: I've slightly changed my original question, please read it again. It's not about passing a status (I understand that only backend can do that), it's about making google understand redirect (automatic changing URL address).